# When should we use an adjective instead of an adverb after verbs(main verb)?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, predicative-complements

Here's the SAT sentence that raised my curiosity:

> Strong wind, sweeping almost ***unchecked*** over great distances, is
>   a prime component of the grassland climate.

Although I know the sentence above is indeed the standard way of expression, I am wondering why shouldn't "unchecked" be replaced by an adverb.

I have done some research and someone suggested that "unchecked" is acting as a complement. If he is right, would anyone please indicate which kind of complement it belongs to and when it is correct to use as above?

I also found this on the Internet. According to The Guide to Grammar and Writing:

> When the participle of an absolute phrase is a form of to be, such as being or having been, the participle is often left out but understood.

Does this help explain my sentence?

Thanks in advance. (I am not a native speaker so please forgive me for possible grammar mistakes in this post.)

Comment: I think you may have fallen into the fallacy of thinking that adverbs need to end in -ly.  "when, where, now, then...." Some participles (e.g. unchecked) decidedly have no -ly form. Others, perhaps unexpectedly, do.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock It is not just about this particular sentence. While in this case one may argue "unchecked" is an adverb(New Oxford American Dictionary says it is not), in cases like "He returned home safe" there is no room for this type of argument.

Comment: I see your point.  _safe_ is definitely an adjective. And returning home safe is not the same as returning home safely. So, the wind was unchecked, not "sweeping".  The question is more interesting than I thought, as it brings into doubt the oft-stated rule that predicate adjectives follow only "linking", stative verbs. e.g.:  http://www.dailywritingtips.com/predicate-complements-2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Strong wind, sweeping almost unchecked over great distances, is a prime component of the grassland climate.

If you change the above sentence to

> Strong wind sweeps unchecked over great distances

it is easier to understand.

"unchecked" complements the subject *wind* at the time it sweeps. That's why it could be called either "predicative-complement" or "quasi-complement". The sentence could be rephrased to

> Strong wind sweeps over great distances and it is unchecked.

The more obvious examples are as follows;

> She came home happy. = She came home and she was happy.

Happy complements the subject when she came home. That's why you don't use "happily".

> He died young. = He died and he was young = He died young when he was young.

Comment: _Strong wind sweeps unchecked over great distances_ ...But you can't complete the whole sentence in this way: _Strong wind sweeps unchecked over great distances, is a prime component of the grassland climate._

Comment: @Rathony Thank you very much. Could you please elaborate a little bit more about "quasi-complement"? I don't quite get when it should be used.

Comment: @Amos "Quasi-Complement" is not often used. He left alone / He lives alone /  He stood motionless. No adverb is used here. / They parted good friends. etc. You can see "good firends" are even a complement here. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Rathony you are truly helpful. Now I get it better. What do think of the explanation I just posted?

Comment: @margana: so are you saying that "sweeps" is to be understood as a noun?  ("...sweeps, [unchecked]... is...")  Why not "...sweeps, [unchecked]...**are**..."  ?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock. No. _Strong wind sweeps unchecked over great distances_ which this answer suggests, does not address the complete sentence from the OP.  I'm saying that, as it stands, the suggested alteration does not immediately fit with the second half of the original.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right and that "unchecked" is a manner adverb.  It could be replaced by "swiftly", for instance.  Why not use "uncheckedly" then?  Because it's not a word (though I don't understand why it's not a word).

Comment: I think participles get a pass on _-ly_; past participles, anyway. **Frightenedly*?

Comment: @Mari-LouA, thanks, I corrected the typo.

Comment: @GregLee Thanks for your answer. Can I ask who is right about "manner adverb"? I don't think "uncheckedly" not being a word can be used to justify that "unchecked" is an adverb.

Comment: @AmosSame, I think it can.  I am taking McCawley's view here (in **The Syntactic Phenomena of English**) that many aspects of our syntactic system work they way they do because syntactic expressions must be fit into a fixed and limited morphological system.

Comment: @AmosSame You're right here. It shouldn't be used as an argument in this case. Here the phrase "almost unchecked" is what is known as a "depictive adjunct" or "predicative adjunct". These are adjuncts which usually describe some entity represented by a noun phrase. They are never adverbs. In this case, the adjunct is describing the subject of the clause *sweeping over great distances* which is decipherable as "the winds". Consider "he ate the pizza naked". The word "naked" is an adjective there because it describes "he", not "eating the pizza".

Comment: @AmosSame But we know its an adjective because of its syntactic properties and morphology, not because of its grammatical function.

Comment: @JohnLawler .. Hmm, but predicative adjuncts - or depictive adjuncts - or whatever you want to call them, wouldn't be adverbs in any case ...

Comment: I don't think "predicative adjunct" -- or "adjunct" for that matter -- means anything specific enough to be turned into a syntactic test. It seems like handwaving to me.

Comment: @JohnLawler Test? I don't know who said anything about one o them! Basically, if it's describing the understood subject of a clause and not the verb or the VP or whatnot then we would expect it to be an adjective, not an adverb: "He died young" not "*He died youngly" or "Unwilling to accept the terms, Max resigned" as opposed to "*Unwillingly to accept the terms, Max resigned"

Comment: @Araucaria, I think "unchecked" is a manner adverb rather than some sort of adjective, because I think it does not, in fact, describe the wind.  The wind is blowing *as though* unchecked.  Compare "He opened the door cleverly, even though he is actually rather stupid", where "cleverly" describes the manner, but not necessarily the person.

Comment: @GregLee Hmm, I can understand that reasoning, but I don't agree. Problem is that because it's sweeping, it's necessarily unchecked, so it's difficult to differentiate. It seems to me to have the same sort of structure as *He stood tall* or *He lay hidden*. Consider "The lion, standing rampant above the door, welcomed all entrants ...." You definitely wouldn't want an adverb there! Just my thoughts ...